# How to partition a set of nodes into subsets that each form a Directed Acyclic Graph

Tags: c#, graph-theory, directed-acyclic-graphs

In a C# project, I have a set of tests to be performed. Each test has its own collection of tests that it depends on.  The network of tests are required to form a Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG).

Using the notation A -> B -> C where A,B,C represent tests, then

C depends on B,
B depends on A.

I already have an algorithm which orders the tests so that I can process them in order so that all the dependencies are respected. That is, the order means each test’s dependencies are evaluated before the test itself is evaluated for the whole Graph.

What I would like to have is an algorithm which first takes a set of tests and can partition them into separate DAG graphs, if any exist.  The tests in each DAG don’t need to be ordered, as that can be done separately. The reason for this is that I could run each independent DAG as a separate Task and gain some efficiencies this way.

So, consider the set of tests A, B, C, D, E, F whose dependencies are:

```
A -> B -> C

D -> C

E -> F
```

From the algorithm I would like 2 sets of Tests,

```
Set 1) A,B,C,D

Set 2) E,F
```

UPDATE: C# code to help with request to Eric.

```
    public class Graph
{
    private List<Node> _nodes = new List<Node>();

    public IReadOnlyList<Node> Nodes => _nodes;

    public void AddNode(Node node)
    {
        _nodes.Add(node);
    }

    public void RemoveRange(IEnumerable<Node> nodes)
    {
        foreach (var item in nodes)
        {
            _nodes.Remove(item);
        }
    }
}

public class Node
{
    public Node(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    private List<Node> _dependants = new List<Node>();

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public IReadOnlyList<Node> Dependents => _dependants;

    public void AddDependent(Node node)
    {
        _dependants.Add(node);
    }
}

public class Set
{
    private List<Node> _elements = new List<Node>();

    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<Node> nodes)
    {
        _elements = new List<Node>(nodes);
    }

    public IReadOnlyList<Node> Elements => _elements;
}

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Set> sets = new List<Set>();

        var graph = new Graph();

        var a = new Node("A");
        var b = new Node("B");
        var c = new Node("C");
        var d = new Node("D");
        var e = new Node("E");
        var f = new Node("F");

        graph.AddNode(a);
        graph.AddNode(b);
        graph.AddNode(c);
        graph.AddNode(d);
        graph.AddNode(e);
        graph.AddNode(f);

        c.AddDependent(b);
        b.AddDependent(a);
        c.AddDependent(d);
        f.AddDependent(e);

        while (graph.Nodes.Count > 0)
        {
            var set = new Set();

            var pickNode = graph.Nodes[0];

            // Get reachable nodes
            // 1. NOT SURE WHAT YOU MEAN HERE AND HOW TO DO THIS IN C# 
            // 2. ALSO, DOES THE SET INCLUDE THE PICKED NODE?
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE 2 :

Code example for sorting nodes

```
    private enum MarkType
    {
        None,
        Permanent,
        Temporary
    }

    private static IEnumerable<T> GetSortedNodes<T>(DirectedGraph<T> directedGraph)
    {
        List<T> L = new List<T>();

        var allNodes = directedGraph.Nodes();

        Dictionary<T, (MarkType, T)> nodePairDictionary = allNodes.ToDictionary(n => n, n => (MarkType.None, n));

        foreach (var node in allNodes)
        {
            var nodePair = nodePairDictionary[node];
            Visit(nodePair);
        }

        return L.Reverse<T>().ToList();

        void Visit((MarkType markType, T node) nodePair)
        {

            if (nodePair.markType == MarkType.Permanent)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (nodePair.markType == MarkType.Temporary)
            {
                throw new Exception("NOT A DAG");
            }

            nodePair.markType = MarkType.Temporary;

            foreach (var dependentNode in directedGraph.Edges(nodePair.node))
            {
                var depNodePair = nodePairDictionary[dependentNode];
                Visit(depNodePair);
            }

            nodePair.markType = MarkType.Permanent;

            L.Insert(0, nodePair.node);
        }

    }
```

Comment: You got off to a good start here. I've added an implementation in my answer that shows how I might solve this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer of pniederh gives a (somewhat over-complicated) version of a union-find algorithm; as I noted in a comment, there is a lot of research into how to make these algorithms efficient.

In your particular case, another algorithm that works is this one:

- Create a type representing an undirected graph.
- Add a node to the graph representing each task.
- Add an edge to the graph -- remember, it is undirected -- representing each dependency.
- Create a list of sets.
- Are there any nodes in the graph? If no, then you're done, and the result is the list of sets.
- Pick any node from the graph.
- Run a graph traversal on that node and accumulate the set of reachable nodes.
- Stick that set into a list.
- Remove all the nodes in that set from the graph.
- Go back to the check for nodes in the graph.

When you're done, you have a list of sets, where each set contains tasks that have some direct or indirect dependency to each other and every task appears in exactly one set.  This is the set of *equivalence classes* introduced by the *symmetric dependency equivalence relation*.

---

UPDATE: There are some additional questions about how to implement this.

Here's a simple and not particularly efficient implementation. The idea here is to build up more and more complex data structures from simpler data structures.

The first thing I want is a multi-dictionary. An ordinary dictionary maps from a key to a value. I want a map from a key to a set of values. We could download any number of implementations via NuGet but it is quick and easy to write our own bare-bones implementation:

```
public class MultiDictionary<K, V>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<K, HashSet<V>> d = new Dictionary<K, HashSet<V>>();
    public void Add(K k, V v)
    {
        if (!d.ContainsKey(k)) d.Add(k, new HashSet<V>());
        d[k].Add(v);
    }
    public void Remove(K k, V v)
    {
        if (d.ContainsKey(k))
        {
            d[k].Remove(v);
            if (d[k].Count == 0) d.Remove(k);
        }
    }
    public void Remove(K k) => d.Remove(k);
    public IEnumerable<V> GetValues(K k) => d.ContainsKey(k) ? d[k] : Enumerable.Empty<V>();
    public IEnumerable<K> GetKeys() => d.Keys;
}
```

I hope you agree this is a straightforward abstract datatype.

Once we have a multidictionary we are very close to having a directed graph. However, we cannot use this multidictionary as a directed graph because it does not represent the concept of a graph node with no outgoing edges. So let's build a simple directed graph type that uses a multidictionary:

```
public class DirectedGraph<T>
{
    private readonly HashSet<T> nodes = new HashSet<T>();
    private readonly MultiDictionary<T, T> edges = new MultiDictionary<T, T>();
    public void AddNode(T node) => nodes.Add(node);
    public void AddEdge(T n1, T n2)
    {
        AddNode(n1);
        AddNode(n2);
        edges.Add(n1, n2);
    }
    public void RemoveEdge(T n1, T n2) => edges.Remove(n1, n2);
    public void RemoveNode(T n)
    {
        // TODO: This algorithm is very inefficient if the graph is
        // TODO: large; can you think of ways to improve it?
        // Remove the incoming edges
        foreach (T n1 in nodes)
            RemoveEdge(n1, n);       
        // Remove the outgoing edges
        foreach (T n2 in edges.GetValues(n).ToList())
            RemoveEdge(n, n2);
        // The node is now isolated; remove it.
        nodes.Remove(n);
    }
    public IEnumerable<T> Edges(T n) => edges.GetValues(n);
    public IEnumerable<T> Nodes() => nodes.Select(x => x);
    public HashSet<T> ReachableNodes(T n) { ??? }
    // We'll come back to this one!
}
```

There are a few subtle points here; do you see why I used `ToList` and `Select`?

OK, we now have a directed graph, to represent our dependency graph. We need an undirected graph for our algorithm. But the easiest way to make an undirected graph is to make a directed graph and just add and remove the edges in pairs!

```
public class UndirectedGraph<T>
{
    private readonly DirectedGraph<T> g = new DirectedGraph<T>();
    public void AddNode(T node) => g.AddNode(node);
    public void AddEdge(T n1, T n2)
    {
        g.AddEdge(n1, n2);
        g.AddEdge(n2, n1);
    }
    public void RemoveEdge(T n1, T n2)
    {
        g.RemoveEdge(n1, n2);
        g.RemoveEdge(n2, n1);
    }
    public void RemoveNode(T n) => g.RemoveNode(n);
    public IEnumerable<T> Edges(T n) => g.Edges(n);
    public IEnumerable<T> Nodes() => g.Nodes();
}
```

Super. To make the conversion easier let's add a helper method to the directed graph:

```
public UndirectedGraph<T> ToUndirected()
{
    var u = new UndirectedGraph<T>();
    foreach (T n1 in nodes)
    {
        u.AddNode(n1);
        foreach (T n2 in Edges(n1))
            u.AddEdge(n1, n2);
    }
    return u;
}
```

Now, the crux of our algorithm is the ability to get the reachable set of nodes given a node. I hope you agree that everything so far has been straightforward.  This is the tricky bit:

```
public HashSet<T> ReachableNodes(T n)
{
    var reachable = new HashSet<T>();
    if (nodes.Contains(n))
    {
        var stack = new Stack<T>();
        stack.Push(n);
        while (stack.Count > 0)
        {
            var current = stack.Pop();
            if (!reachable.Contains(current))
            {
                reachable.Add(current);
                foreach (T n2 in Edges(current))
                    stack.Push(n2);
            }
        }
    }
    return reachable;
}
```

This is a depth-first traversal of a directed graph which detects cycles and returns the transitive closure of the given node. **Study this algorithm carefully because it is the key one to understand**.

We'll add a helper method to our undirected graph:

```
public HashSet<T> ReachableNodes(T n) => g.ReachableNodes(n);
```

And now we have all the parts we need to make our algorithm. We just translate the algorithm description I gave directly into code:

```
static IEnumerable<HashSet<T>> GetEquivalenceClasses<T>(DirectedGraph<T> d)
{
    var u = d.ToUndirected();
    var results = new List<HashSet<T>>();
    while (u.Nodes().Any())
    {
        T current = u.Nodes().First();
        HashSet<T> reachable = u.ReachableNodes(current);
        results.Add(reachable);
        foreach (T n in reachable)
            u.RemoveNode(n);
    }
    return results;
}
```

Let's take it for a spin:

```
    var d = new DirectedGraph<string>();
    d.AddEdge("A", "B");
    d.AddEdge("B", "C");
    d.AddEdge("D", "C");
    d.AddEdge("E", "F");
    foreach (var eq in GetEquivalenceClasses(d))
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", eq));
```

And sure enough:

```
A,B,C,D
E,F
```

Make sense?

---

UPDATE: Removing nodes is the expensive part, and I just realized, we don't need to do that.  A non-destructive version of the algorithm is:

```
static IEnumerable<HashSet<T>> GetEquivalenceClasses<T>(DirectedGraph<T> d)
{
    var u = d.ToUndirected();
    var results = new List<HashSet<T>>();
    var done = new HashSet<T>();
    foreach(T current in u.Nodes())
    {
        if (done.Contains(current))
          continue;
        HashSet<T> reachable = u.ReachableNodes(current);
        results.Add(reachable);
        foreach(T n in reachable)
          done.Add(n);
    }
    return results;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Eric. My knowledge of Graph Theory is very limited. As such there are a couple of questions I have with your answer. I am confused by what you mean in bullet 3. Especially the 'remember it is undirected bit'. Bullet 7, I am lost with. Would you be able to provide a C# snippet for this please? I will edit my original post and add some C# code for you to use if this would help. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: @Cleve: My point in bullet 3 is just to remember that your directed graph of dependencies is not all the information you need; you need to know the dependencies in *both directions*. The algorithm in point 7 is just the standard algorithm for computing the transitive closure of a relation; I discussed that a bit here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/02/08/making-the-code-read-like-the-spec/

Comment: Wow. Thank you very much Eric! This is amazing. I'm still trying to digest everything. In answer to your question about the use of `ToList` and `Select` would I be right to say you need to reify the enumerable as you are changing the collection?

Comment: @Cleve: In the case of the `ToList`, yes, since the loop is enumerating the collection and the loop body is modifying it, I want to make sure that we're enumerating a copy.  In the case of the `Select`, this is to deal with the problem of "what if some jerk caller casts the `Ienumerable` to `HashSet`, and now I've given some foolish person or hacker a reference to one of my private data structures, and they can screw around with it.

Comment: Eric, I cannot thank you enough for your help. My ultimate goal is to execute the tests (represented by graph nodes) in an order that respects all the dependencies. It is my belief that to order the tests to respect the dependencies involves doing what I think is called a ‘Topological Sort’?  I will need to apply this sort on each of the sets that your  `GetEquivalanceClasses()` method produces.  So, in my original example, after sorting I would have 2 ordered sets: (1) { A,B,C,D} (unsorted)-> { A, B, D, C} (sorted) and (2) {E, F} (unsorted) -> {E,F}(sorted).  Continued below...

Comment: My problem is that I want to use your code, but I can’t see how to apply a ‘Topological Sort’ using your API. I know it’s a big ask, but would you be kind enough to help here? Also, to do any of this I need to be sure the DG is in fact a DAG, which I take to mean there are no cycles in the graph. Is there a way your DG class be extended to have an .`IsDAG()` method ?

Comment: @Cleve: If you do a web search for "Eric Lippert topological sort" you'll find the articles I wrote on how to make a toposort with and without a cycle detector from 2004. I wrote them for JavaScript, but perhaps you can see how to make them work in C#.

Comment: @Cleve: Or, you can just adapt the existing code I already gave. The code which does the depth first search has a check to see if the node has been found already. A DAG is a graph where every depth first search *never* finds a node that is already in the graph.

Comment: Hi Eric, thanks for the tips. I have updated my original post to show you my effort. Sadly, it doesn't work and I can't see why. Plus, the parameter to my `GetSortedNodes` method, shouldn't be a directed graph really. I really need it to be a set of nodes from your `GetEquivalenceClasses` method, or more precisely a directed graph of each set of nodes from that method. A real mess if I'm honest. Are you able to help please?

Comment: Hi Eric, can you clarify, does the `DirectedGraph,AddEdge(n1, n2)` mean n1 depends on n2, or n2 depends on n1 ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In pseudo-code such an algorithm could look something like this:

```
Create a list of buckets
foreach (Node n in Nodes)
{
    Find a bucket that contains n, or create a new bucket for it.
    foreach (Node dependentNode in n.DependentNodes)
    {
        if (dependentNode is in any bucket)
        {
            move n and its dependencies to that bucket;
        }
        else
        {
            add depenentNode to the same bucket as N;
        }
    }
}
```

After iterating over all your nodes, the buckets should now represent distinct sets without interdependencies.

Note: I strongly suspect that this is not the most efficient algorithm. But for a limited number of nodes, it should be sufficient.

As always, I would recommend to provide a generous amount of unit testing to ensure correctness, and profiling in case of performance issues.

Here is a minimal implementation as a unit test for your example:

```
[TestFixture]
public class PartitionTests
{
    public class Node
    {
        private List<Node> subNodes = new List<Node>();

        public Node(string name)
        {
            this.Name = name;
        }
        public IEnumerable<Node> DependentNodes { get { return this.subNodes; } }

        public string Name { get; }

        internal void AddDependentNode(Node subNode)
        {
            subNodes.Add(subNode);
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            //just to make debugging easier in this example
            return this.Name;
        }
    }

    [Test]
    public void PartitionTest1()
    {
        #region prepare
        Node A = new Node("A");
        Node B = new Node("B");
        Node C = new Node("C");
        Node D = new Node("D");
        Node E = new Node("E");
        Node F = new Node("F");

        A.AddDependentNode(B);
        B.AddDependentNode(C);
        D.AddDependentNode(C);
        E.AddDependentNode(F);

        var allNodes = new List<Node>() { A, B, C, D, E, F };
        #endregion

        #region Implementation
        var buckets = new List<List<Node>>();
        foreach (var n in allNodes)
        {
            var existingBucket = buckets.FirstOrDefault(b => b.Contains(n));
            if (existingBucket == null)
            {
                existingBucket = new List<Node>() { n };
            }
            foreach (var dependentNode in n.DependentNodes)
            {
                var otherBucket = buckets.FirstOrDefault(b => b.Contains(dependentNode));
                if (otherBucket == null)
                {
                    existingBucket.Add(dependentNode);
                }
                else
                {
                    existingBucket.Remove(n);
                    otherBucket.Add(n);
                    foreach (var alreadyPlacedNode in existingBucket)
                    {
                        existingBucket.Remove(alreadyPlacedNode);
                        if (!otherBucket.Contains(alreadyPlacedNode))
                        {
                            otherBucket.Add(alreadyPlacedNode);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!buckets.Contains(existingBucket) && existingBucket.Any())
            {
                buckets.Add(existingBucket);
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region test
        Assert.AreEqual(2, buckets.Count, "Expect two buckets");
        Assert.AreEqual(4, buckets[0].Count);  //we should not rely on the order of buckets here
        Assert.AreEqual(2, buckets[1].Count);
        CollectionAssert.Contains(buckets[0], A);
        CollectionAssert.Contains(buckets[0], B);
        CollectionAssert.Contains(buckets[0], C);
        CollectionAssert.Contains(buckets[0], D);
        CollectionAssert.Contains(buckets[1], E);
        CollectionAssert.Contains(buckets[1], F);
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI the algorithm you are describing is an example of a "union-find" algorithm, because it requires two operations: *find* the bucket associated with a given item, and *union* two buckets together when it turns out that they need to be the same bucket. If you do a literature search you will find many papers on this subject. An overview of some techniques is here: http://docsdrive.com/pdfs/ansinet/itj/2003/240-249.pdf

Comment: Both pniederh and Eric, thanks for your replies. Much appreciated.